# How to specialize Iterator by its value type, in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, template-specialization

Is it possible to specialize an Iterator template parameter by its `value_type`?

I have a function with the following prototype.

```
template<typename InputIterator>
void f(InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

And I want to handle specially if `InputIterator::value_type` is `SomeSpecificType.`

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Is this for use with a template specialization? Is there a reason you can't just use the above and reference InputIterator::value_type in the body?

Comment: Hm, you could do all sorts of typetraiting stuff, but if you already want an _input_iterator with a specific value type, wouldn't that mean that whatever you get is a derived class with base class `std::iterator<input_iterator_tag, YourCrazyType>`? So you wouldn't need any templating at all, just one fixed function.

Comment: @Kerrek: no it doesn't mean that. Iterators do not share a common base class. Case in point: pointers are iterators.

Comment: @Kerrek: `std::iterator<...>` is not polymorphic and doesn't implement any useful operations.

Comment: You're right, sorry for that. One more thing learned about iterators :-) Luc's answer below nails it nicely.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use some intermediate structs to get the partial template specialisation that you need. Something like this should do the trick

```
template<typename T, typename V>
struct f_impl
{
  static void f( T first, T last ) {...}; //Default version
};

template<typename T>
struct f_impl<T, SomeSpecificType>
{
   static void f(T first,T last) {...}; //Specialisation
};

template<typename InputIterator> void f(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
{
  f_impl<
      InputIterator,
      typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type
  >::f(first,last);
};
```

Comment: `typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type` would be better than `typename InputIterator::value_type`.

Answer (score 8):

Using SFINAE, assuming `enable_if[_c]` and `is_same` are either from Boost or `<type_traits>` (and are appropriately qualified with either `boost::` or `std::` respectively):

```
template<typename InputIterator>
typename enable_if<
    !is_same<
        typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type,
        SomeSpecificType
    >::value
>::type
f(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
{
    // Default implementation.
}

template<typename InputIterator>
typename enable_if<
    is_same<
        typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type,
        SomeSpecificType
    >::value
>::type
f(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
{
    // Special case
}
```

In the Boost case, use `boost::enable_if_c` for something similar to the above. You can use `boost::enable_if` and get rid of the `::value` but then must also use e.g. `boost::disable_if`.

Comment: Note that `boost::enable_if` wants a metafunction whereas `std::enable_if` wants a `bool` value. The proper Boost corollary in this context is `boost::enable_if_c`.

Comment: D'oh; that's what I get for reading the code and only skimming the surrounding text. :-P

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename T::value_type, SomeType>::value, void>::type
f(T first, T second);
```

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes: you can constrain the second version of `f` too to remove the ambiguity

Comment: @Martino: you can have as many overloads as you need as long as you correctly `enable_if` each one.

Comment: @Dani: I see no simple way to add that constraint, without a wrapper function call like in @Michael Anderson's answer.

Comment: @Martinho: I have a lot of operator overloading in AXE, all done with SFINAE facilities. You wouldn't be able to do it any differently, when you need to preserve perfect forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

This will work. This type of specialization only works with structs, so I can't do this with a function.

```
template <typename InputIterator, typename ValueType = typename InputIterator::value_type>
struct foobar
{
    static void invoke(InputIterator first, InputIterator second)
    {
        // ...
    }
};

template <typename InputIterator>
struct foobar<InputIterator, SomeSpecificType>
{
    static void invoke(InputIterator first, InputIterator second)
    {
        // ...
    }
};
```

This shouldn't require you to set the type. It should be inferred automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Call me naive, but why wouldn't the following suffice?

```
struct MyType; // the only type I want

#include <iterator>
typedef std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, MyType> MyIt;

void f(const MyIt & begin, const MyIt & end)
{
   /* ... */
}
```

---

OK, forget that above, that was nonsense. Here's a way to do it, which is just Luc's correct answer from above, for C++0x:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

// "int" is our desired iterator value type, "void" is f's return type.
template <typename It>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<int, typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type>::value, void>::type
f(const It & begin, const It & end) { /* your function here */ }

int main()
{
  std::vector<double> x;
  std::vector<int> y;

  //f(x.cbegin(), x.cend()); // error
  f(y.cbegin(), y.cend());   // works
}
```

Comment: Now attempt to do anything at all useful with `begin` or `end` in this specialized `f`.

Comment: Right, I see. The inheritance from std::iterator is only for typetraiting purposes... never mind then. The real answer would probably involve some typetraiting work after all.